# NodeJs giving TypeError that Post is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on NodeJs application. I am trying to save posts in database and I am getting this error after making a post request from postman.

```
** <pre>TypeError: Post is not a constructor**
**warnings--
(node:6704) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new 
Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
(node:6704) DeprecationWarning: Listening to events on the Db class has been deprecated and will be removed in the next major version.**
```

**post schema**

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose')

const Post_Schema=mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now()  
    }
});
exports.module=mongoose.model('Posts',Post_Schema)
```

**post.js**

```
const express=require('express')
const router=express.Router();

const Post=require('../../models/Post')
router.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    //creating new post with our 'POST MODEL'
    const post=new Post({
        title:req.body.title,
        description:req.body.description

    });
    //saving in DB
    //post.save() return a promise
     post.save()
     .then(data=>res.json(data))
     .catch(err=>res.json({msg:err}))
}
)



module.exports=router
```

**app.js**

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const PORT=process.env.PORT || 5000
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
// const cors=require('cors')
require('dotenv/config')

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:'false'}))
// app.use(cors())
//init middleware
app.use('/posts',require('./routes/api/posts'))


//connect to DB
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
{ useNewUrlParser: true },{ useUnifiedTopology: true },
()=>console.log('connected to DB!'))

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running at port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Post` instead of `Posts` because mongoose add `s` to the name of collection automatically

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Post',Post_Schema)
```

also when you want tp connect to the database, passing this option `{useUnifiedTopology: true}` as arguments, so just try like this

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connected to DB!");
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server is running at port ${PORT}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: changing Posts to 'Post' doesn't work either.

Comment: change the mongoose.conncet also, and check agian, and check the path of `const Post=require('../../models/Post')` , this path is correc?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh!
I was doing

```
exports.module =mongoose.model('Posts',Post_Schema)
```

which is wrong.
The correct way is to export a module is

```
module.exports=mongoose.model('Posts',Post_Schema)`
```